# make book.randomID key in amazon dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

for some reason I want to use **book.randomID** as key in amazon DynamoDB table using java code. when i tried id added a new field in the item named "book.randomID"

```
List<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
        keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("conceptDetailInfo.conceptId").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH)); // Partition
```

and here is the json structure

```
{  
   "_id":"123",
   "book":{  
      "chapters":{  
         "chapterList":[  
            {  
               "_id":"11310674",
               "preferred":true,
               "name":"1993"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      "randomID":"1234"
   }
}
```

so is it possible to use such element as key. if yes how can we use it as key

Answer (score 0):

When creating DynamoDB tables AWS limits it to the types `String`, `Binary` and `Number`. Your attribute `book.random` seems to be a `String`.

As long as it's not one of the other [data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) like `List`, `Map` or `Set` you should be fine.

Just going to AWS console and trying it out worked for me:

[image: Table Books with nested Primary key book.randomId]

Comment: when i create an item i get "book.randomID" as single field name (as i have already mentioned in the question instead of using the field "randomID" from the "book") like this

`{  
   "_id":"123",
   "book.randomID":"1234"
   "book":{  
      "chapters":{  
         "chapterList":[  
            {  
               "_id":"11310674",
               "preferred":true,
               "name":"1993"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      "randomID":"1234"
   }
}`